# How to Update or Replace records all DBF in one folder based on fields in all table with SQL via ODBC in VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, odbc, visual-foxpro, dbf

How to Update or Replace records all DBFs in one folder based on fields across tables with SQL via ODBC in VB.NET?.

If there is another best solution.
I mean the fields in all database tables in one folder named "ITM" So I want to change or update e.g. "TEST R 1000" to TEST RC 1000 LTP"
If there are other alternatives through other database providers please recommend.
Example screenshot I attach below so example I have DBF table A,B,C,D,E I want to change "TEST R 1000" to TEST RC 1000 LTP" or that I marking yellow

[image: TABEL DBF]
[image: Error code]

```
Imports System.Data.Odbc

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
    
    Private Sub Update_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Update.Click
        Dim connection As New OdbcConnection
        Dim strConnection As String
        Dim pathDBF As String
        Dim strSQL As String
        pathDBF = "D:\DBF"
        strConnection = "Driver={Microsoft dBASE Driver (*.dbf)};DriverID=277;Dbq=" & pathDBF
        connection.Open()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: There are literally thousands of examples of how to execute update commands via ODBC, many of those on this very site.   You need to update your question with the exact aspect of this that you're struggling with and concise explanation of why.  Perhaps start with some general reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/update-sql-command?view=sql-server-ver16.  This does talk about Visual FoxPro rather than DBase, but they are probably close enough to get you started

Comment: @Hursey , thanks reply from you. i've changed from dbase to visual fox pro. I have also updated the screenshots for the solution to the problem

Comment: IMHO, forget using ODBC with VFP and use OLEDB instead. Also be sure to compile for 32 bits (target platform x86). You might use 64 bits Sybase ADS drivers by paying them if you want to check and try them on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it is VFP, there is no official ODBC driver after version 6.x. There are ODBC drivers for Sybase (ADS) but as far as I know they are not for free unless it is local data (it has been over 10 years I have last tried them).

Instead you should use [VFP OLEDB driver - VFPOLEDB](https://github.com/VFPX/VFP9SP2Hotfix3)

Next, tablenames A,B,C,...E is not good because of historical reasons, let's instead assume tableNames are A_,B_, ...E_ then you could do what you are asking for easily:

```
import System.Data.OleDb
Private Sub Update_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Update.Click

    Dim pathDBF = "d:\DBF"

    Using cn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection($"Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source={pathDBF}")
        Dim tableNames = "A_, B_, C_, D_, E_"
        cn.Open()

        For Each tableName In tableNames.Split(","c)
            New OleDbCommand($"update {tableName.Trim()} set Item=""TEST RC 1000 LTP"" where Item==""TEST R 1000""", cn).ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next

        cn.Close()
    End Using

End Sub
```

EDIT: Updated version for old VB versions:

```
import System.Data.OleDb
Private Sub Update_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Update.Click

Dim pathDBF = "d:\DBF"

Using cn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection($"Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source={pathDBF}")
    Dim tableNames = "A_, B_, C_, D_, E_"
    cn.Open()

    For Each tableName In tableNames.Split(","c)
            Using cmd = New OleDbCommand(String.Format("update {0} set Item=""TEST RC 1000 LTP"" where Item==""TEST R 1000""", tableName.Trim()), cn)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            end using
        Next
        cn.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but I have an error with the code `New OleDbCommand($"update {tableName.Trim()} set Item=""TEST RC 1000 LTP"" where Item==""TEST R 1000""", cn).ExecuteNonQuery()` . I'm using VS 2015. I also update the error screenshot

Comment: @roy, 2015 is old, that misses $"....". I am updating for 2015.

Comment: thanks reply from you but there is a Syntax error in the code `New OleDbCommand`

Comment: @roy, my bad, I always forget about VB's weird behaviors, being a C# guy. Edited it.

Comment: Thank you very much you are right a teacher to me. I tried very perfectly and I tried with five thousand records running very fast and there is only one less if it can be done there is a message box that states that it has finished updating or also failed

Comment: @roy, you can add your messagebox just after second using. If there is a possibility for it to fail (very slim chance on a local folder) you can wrap it with try .. catch.

Comment: you mean the messagebox after "end using" with code `MessageBox.Show("updated", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)` but "updated" the display 5 times

Comment: @roy, after last end using. It is after the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the sorry answer if I reply late and you are my teacher.